# decomposing a floating-point number into numbers from a list

Tags: python, list

Given a floating-point number `f=0.0...0.999` and a `list k=[0.500, 0.333, 0.250, 0.200, 0.166, 0.143, 0.125, 0.111, 0.100, 0.091]`. It is necessary to decompose the number `f` into the numbers from the list `k`. If there is no exact match, then you need to subtract from the number `f` in increments of `0.001` until the initial condition is met. that is, `f >= sum ki`. My code does not work for all cases. How to solve the problem?

```
import itertools

def func(n,l):
   return [a for i in [itertools.product(l,repeat=x) for x in range(1,20)] for a in i if sum(a) == n]

float_num=0.176
k=[0.500, 0.333, 0.250, 0.200, 0.166, 0.143, 0.125, 0.111, 0.100, 0.091]

decomp=func(float_num, k)
print('decompose of', float_num, ':')

if decomp == []:    
    while decomp == []:
        float_num = float_num - 0.001
        decomp=func(float_num, k)
       
        if float_num == 0.091:
            decomp=func(float_num, k)
            break
        elif float_num < 0.091:
            decomp=[0]
            break

print(decomp)
```

Comment: Only three of the numbers in your `k` list are exactly representable as floats (the ones that are negative powers of 2), and your target number isn't exact either.  They're *never* going to add up exactly, except by sheer chance.

Comment: Even if you  do it on paper, there will be always numbers that can't be represented by the list shown, e.g. all number between 0.09 and 0.1. You should have a list of the negative powers of 2 (as @jasonharper said) and then you might have a  chance to approximate a chosen number.

Comment: You can either use a "close to" function to check for equality, or you can multiply all the numbers by 1000 and use integers.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I edited the question to get my point across. the main thing for me is to divide the number f into elements from k, the sum of which will be equal to or less than f.

Comment: Please add precise info what does not work, because that is not an error description. So, what is the input, what is the actual output and what is the expected output. Further, two suggestions: Step through the code in a debugger to find out where it goes wrong. Secondly, I believe Python has a "decimal" class, which can actually represent 0.33 exactly (BTW: Shouldn't that be 0.333 in your code?)

Comment: Thanks guys! The issue is resolved. The float number was multiplied by 1000 and converted to integers

Answer (score 0):

This code should give you the closest you can get to the target:

```
target=0.8
mini=1000
for i in range(0, len(k)+1):
    for selection in itertools.combinations(k, i):
        m=sum(selection)
        if np.abs(target-m)<mini:
            mini=np.abs(target-m)
            print (selection, m)
```

I guess, you can take it from here:)